# Use requirements defined in extras_require of setup.py

Tags: python, heroku, setup.py

I have a library, which has a demo website. The setup.py for the library looks like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        ...
    ],
    extras_require={
        "test": [
            ...
        ],
        "demo": [
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
)
```

I run the demo on Heroku. How do I tell heroku to do `pip install -e .[demo]`?

My reading of [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip) was somewhat fruitful. I've added `requirements.txt` which does

```
# heroku needs this
-e .[demo]
```

But perhaps there is a better way? I'm aiming to solve this without creating a requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `extras_require`, but if your issue is to adapt the requirements to the platform, you could try the following:

First find a way to check inside `setup.py` if it runs on Heroku or not, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383450/how-can-i-detect-herokus-environment).

And then you can use [this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636870/conditional-requirements-in-setup-py) to adapt the `install_requires` variable of `setuptools.setup` to what you need on Heroku.